# Discord.py Rewrite, get timestamp that changes

Tags: python, discord.py

So i saw a bot that printed how long ago a message was sent in the footer of an embed, how is this possible. The time changed[image]

Comment: It is possible by taking the current time and the time when the message was sent, calculating the difference, and printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embed object has a timestamp parameter. From there you can supply the message creation date as value

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at